# How to set a custom/default value to the value coming from database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

How to set a custom/default value to the value coming from database?
I've the following color code values which I need to match/set for the values from the DB.

```
**Values from DB**     **Default value**
At Risk -                 Red
On Track -                Green
Needs Attention -         Yellow
```

Please let me know how to tweak my below code to get the expected o/p.

```
String colorStatus = userObj.setStatus();
            userCodeValue.setStatus(colorStatus);
            /*String yellowColor = "yellow";
            if(colorStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Need Attention")){
                vlcValue.setStatus(yellowColor);
            }*/
```

Comment: At Risk can have other value than Red?

Comment: Requirement is like that and also

Comment: it doesn't matter what is our default/custom we give, ideally I want something that can be matched with what I give as custom value

Answer (score 1):

You can make your mapping static using enums. The first element is an interface to obtain the default color:

```
public interface ColorMapper {
   Color defaultValue();
}
```

The color enum:

```
public enum  Color {

   RED, GREEN, YELLOW
}
```

and the static mapping between your original values and default values:

```
public enum Status implements ColorMapper {

    AT_RISK("At Risk") {
        @Override
        public Color defaultValue() {
            return Color.RED;
        }
    },
    ON_TRACK("On Track") {
        @Override
        public Color defaultValue() {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }
    },
    NEEDS_ATTENTION("Needs Attention") {
        @Override
        public Color defaultValue() {
            return Color.YELLOW;
        }
    };

    private String code;

    Status(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

This mapping is static and pretty clear at any moment.
Another option is to create a `Map<String,String>` where to keep your mapping between the database values and default values:

```
 @Service
 public class MyService{
     private static final Map<String,String> defaultMappingValues;
     public MyService(){
          defaultMappingValues.put("At Risk", "RED");
          defaultMappingValues.put("On Track", "Green");
          defaultMappingValues.put("Needs Attention","Yellow");
     }

 }
```

and when you will need default value for `At Risk` you will call

```
defaultMappingValues.get("At Risk");
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, Is there any way we can make it simpler since I'm using Springboot with JPA                                                                                                                     Can I write something in my serviceImpl class?

Answer (score 0):

```
// color code functionality to be included
            String colorStatus = vlcObj.getColorStatus();
            vlcValue.setColortStatus(colorStatus);
            String yellowColor = "yellow";
            String greenColor = "green";
            String redColor = "red";

            if(colorStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("NeedsAttention")){
                vlcValue.setColortStatus(yellowColor);
            }
            if(colorStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("AtRisk")){
                vlcValue.setColortStatus(redColor);
            }
            if(colorStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("None")){
                vlcValue.setColortStatus(greenColor);
            }if(colorStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("OnTrack")){
                vlcValue.setColortStatus(greenColor);
            }
```